# SMCalloutView; clicking on Annotation presents calloutview, but immediately disappears

Tags: ios, mkannotation

Im using `SMCalloutView` [link here](https://github.com/nfarina/calloutview) for 'UICalloutView' for my annotations. It works in that when I click on an annotation, the callout appears. I can dismiss the callout by click on the same annotation again, or the map itself. However a strange behaviour occurs in this scenario;

I select an annotation which presents the 'SMCalloutView'. I then select another annotation (without click the original annotation, or map, to dismiss it) and as a result, the original 'SMCalloutView' disappears, but the new one appears, and immediately disappears (blinking effect). I followed the example, there isnt a great deal of documentation on github but the coding example is fairly well explained, here is my code;

MapViewController.m

```
@interface MapViewController ()<MKMapViewDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate,SMCalloutViewDelegate>

-(void)viewDidLoad{
 //code omitted

 // create our custom callout view
self.calloutView = [SMCalloutView platformCalloutView];
self.calloutView.delegate = self;

}


#pragma mark - MKMapView delegate methods

 - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
 {
    if([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    return nil;

    NSString *annotationIdentifier = @"PinViewAnnotation";

    SandwichAnnotationView *pinView = (SandwichAnnotationView *) [mv dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:annotationIdentifier];


    if (!pinView)
    {
    pinView = [[SandwichAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:annotationIdentifier];

    pinView.canShowCallout = NO;


    }
    else
    {
        pinView.annotation = annotation;
        pinView.canShowCallout=YES;
   }

    return pinView;

}

 - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)annotationView {



    if (mapView == self.map) {


        // apply the MKAnnotationView's basic properties
        self.calloutView.title = annotationView.annotation.title;
        self.calloutView.subtitle = annotationView.annotation.subtitle;

        // Apply the MKAnnotationView's desired calloutOffset (from the top-middle of the view)
        self.calloutView.calloutOffset = annotationView.calloutOffset;

        // create a disclosure button for comparison
        UIButton *disclosure = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        [disclosure addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(disclosureTapped)]];
        self.calloutView.rightAccessoryView = disclosure;

        // iOS 7 only: Apply our view controller's edge insets to the allowable area in which the callout can be displayed.
        if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1)
            self.calloutView.constrainedInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.topLayoutGuide.length, 0, self.bottomLayoutGuide.length, 0);


        // This does all the magic.
        [self.calloutView presentCalloutFromRect:annotationView.bounds inView:annotationView constrainedToView:self.map animated:YES];
    }
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didDeselectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {

    [self.calloutView dismissCalloutAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: I think the 2nd one has a reference to the old one. when 1st one remove from super it just also remove the second one